# I can't get my importxml statement to work - XML import problem or XPath problem?

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import data from a publicly available XML source into my Google Sheet. The data is available as a direct link from an HTML representation - the XML file contains the same data.
Reference: https://cordis.europa.eu/project/rcn/214839/factsheet/en and https://cordis.europa.eu/project/rcn/214839_en.xml

I've been browsing various different sources, and nothing helps so far. It seems that Google can read the data because of the statements

```
IMPORTXML("https://cordis.europa.eu/project/rcn/214839_en.xml", "*")
```

and

```
=IMPORTXML("https://cordis.europa.eu/project/rcn/214839_en.xml", "//*")
```

produce results.

However, simple XPath statements such as `//rcn` or `/project/rcn/text()` bark back at me with an "N/A" result.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That XML document has a default namespace declaration with `http://cordis.europa.eu` URI in the root element.

Comment: Yes it does - but that is perfectly valid XML AFAIK (and w3schools.com XML validator sells me so, too)
If it werent valid XML, then the "*" shouldn't have imported anything, shouldn't it?

Comment: I'm pointing you to the well known problem when trying to select with the `//rcn` expression meaning that the element `rcn`  is under the empty namespace...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the local-name function.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://cordis.europa.eu/project/rcn/214839_en.xml","//*[local-name()='rcn']")
```